# html javascript Count user defined number click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve user defined number count click. The problem is, its keep prompting user, i want user to be promoted once only.

Below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function clickCounter() {
  var person=prompt("Please enter your number");
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = Number(person)-1;
      } else {
        localStorage.clickcount = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
  <p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>

  </body>
  </html>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function clickCounter() {
  var person=prompt("Please enter your number");
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      if (localStorage.clickcount) {
        localStorage.clickcount = Number(person)-1;
      } else {
        localStorage.clickcount = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
  <p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prompt the user only when `localStorage.clickcount` is `null`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function save(event) {
      const userInput = getUserInput();
      localStorage.clickcount = userInput;
      localStorage.userInput = userInput;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    function getUserInput() {
      const number = document.querySelector('#number-input').value || 0;
      return number;
    }
    function clickCounter() {
        if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
          if (localStorage.clickcount > 0) {
            localStorage.clickcount--;
          } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = getUserInput();
          }
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
            "You have clicked the button " +
            localStorage.clickcount +
            " time(s).";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
            "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
        }
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <label for="number">Please enter your number:</label>
    <input type="number" min="1" id="number-input" name="number">
    <button onclick="save(event)" type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  <p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
  <p>
    Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will
    continue to count (is not reset).
  </p>
  <script>
    (function() {
        if (localStorage.userInput) {
          document.querySelector('#number-input').value = localStorage.userInput;
        }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

here is a stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7wink9?file=index.html)

Comment: nothing is happening...all I want is it should count click user specified. For example user enter value 10 then counter click go in reverse 9,8,7 till 1 and then it stop.

Comment: @kwtbazaar I've updated my answer It should work as you want it right now

Comment: can we put input filed with button save instead of prompt?

Comment: @kwtbazaar I've updated my answer and the example. I hope that's what you wanted

Comment: After refresh ...it removed the entered number from input filed. is there anyway i can show or preserved entered number.

Comment: @kwtbazaar you want the number to stay in the input ?

Comment: yes...it wont change until user put new number and save.

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding a self executing function that will set the input value after the html is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Based on your code I suppose you need a per person click count. So here's a snippet for that. I've replaced the prompt with a numeric input box.

```js
// localStorage not available in the (sandboxed) snippet
// so here is a dummy for it, with a stored dummy person #1
const localStoreDummy = {
  clickCount: { person1Count: 5 }
};

document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "count") {
    return doCount();
  }
}

function doCount(evt) {
  const result = document.querySelector("#result");

  if (typeof localStoreDummy !== "undefined") {
    // replaced prompt with numeric input
    let person = document.querySelector("input[type=number]").value;

    if (!person || +person < 1) {
      return alert("No (valid) number entered!");
    }

    if (localStoreDummy.clickCount &&
      localStoreDummy.clickCount[`person${person}Count`]) {
      // found the user, add 1 to his/her counter
      localStoreDummy.clickCount[`person${person}Count`] += 1;
    } else {
      // the person does not exist within 'localStoreDummy.clickCount', 
      // so create a person for the entered number
      localStoreDummy.clickCount = {
        ...localStoreDummy.clickCount,
        [`person${person}Count`]: 1
      };

    }
    result.textContent = `You (person #${person}) have clicked the button ${
        localStoreDummy.clickCount[`person${person}Count`]} time(s).`;
  } else {
    result.textContent = `Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...`;
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="number" min="1"> Type you number
  <button id="count">Click me!</button>
</p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
```

Comment: So you just want to register (and 'remember') all clicks from everyone visiting the page? In that case the `prompt` value is useless imho.

Comment: Ok, have it your way. If you change your mind [see this jsFiddle](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/woap03zs)